# JOIN 3 Table include not existing as null

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, cross-join

I was working on attendance management web viewer and need some guide on querying the data

I have 3 tables:

1. List of date :
   [date table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1URXq.png)
2. List of Employee : [employee table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XB0H.png)
3. Attendance log : [attendance log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13rga.png)

I want to query my data to show like this

Example:

```
dates      | pin | time
2020-10-01 | 1   | 08:00:00
2020-10-01 | 2   | NULL
2020-10-01 | 3   | NULL
2020-10-02 | 1   | 08:01:00
2020-10-02 | 2   | NULL
2020-10-02 | 3   | NULL
2020-10-03 | 1   | 08:03:00
2020-10-03 | 2   | NULL
2020-10-03 | 3   | NULL
2020-10-04 | 1   | NULL
2020-10-04 | 2   | NULL
2020-10-04 | 3   | NULL
```

So, doesnt matter if there is no data on attendance table, the query still show all the date and pin list with NULL value,
My knowledge in MySQL is limited, at most i can only do JOIN Query but the result is only correct on the date part to show all the dates but not show all the user.

My Query:

```
SELECT d.dates, a.pin, u.name, a.time
FROM att_dates AS d -- This is the table with all days
LEFT JOIN att AS a ON d.dates = a.dates
LEFT JOIN att_user u ON a.pin = u.pin
GROUP BY dates, pin
ORDER BY d.dates
```

Here's the copy of the DB on SQL Fiddle
SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91e1ea/2

Comment: `FROM date_table d CROSS JOIN employee_table e LEFT JOIN attend_table a ON d.date=a.date AND e.emp_id=a.emp_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `cross join`ing the dates and users to generate all possible combinations, and then bringing the attendance table with a `left join`:

```
SELECT d.dates, u.pin, u.name, a.time
FROM att_dates AS d
CROSS JOIN att_user u
LEFT JOIN att AS a ON d.dates = a.dates AND a.pin = u.pin
GROUP BY d.dates, u.pin, u.name
ORDER BY d.dates
```

Comment: The `select` columns are inconsistent with the `group by` columns.  So even if the database happens to accept this, it is a malformed query.